# While importing CSV getting this error DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string

Tags: php, mysql, csv, datetime

I'm importing data from CSV file into database through HTML form, sometime it works fine and sometime it throws an error `DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (23/06/2015 12:00)`

Following is the code where it throws error

```
$DepDate = $emapData['1']; //Format is 23/06/2015 12:00
$depdatetime = new DateTime($DepDate); //Here it throws error
$date_depart = $depdatetime->format('Y-m-d');
$time_depart = $depdatetime->format('H:i');
```

Note: I was using `explode` and it worked fine but i wana use `new DateTime();`

Comment: [Date formats in PHP](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) says that using `/` as the separator assumes US format, using `-` assumes UK/European format; so `23/06/2015` with the `/` is US format, and there is no month 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime() does not understand the format you are providing.  It can accept a range of formats including [ISO8601](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.iso8601), but not `23/06/2015 12:00`.  Note @MarkBaker's comment that the `/` separator you are using implies US date formatting where the first position is the month, and there is no month 23.

If you cannot change the `/`, you can use the method [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to specify a format matching your actual data format.

Comment: just wondering, in some cases when the code in my question works, so assuming then date format was like 10/06/2015(D/M/Y), so it convert the date format to (Y-m-d) like this (2015-06-10) or like this (2015-10-06) ?

Comment: Yes it would "work" in the sense of not producing an error message, but your day and month would be reversed.

Comment: Damn, wondering why my client didn't notice the change in dates

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and explicitly set the format of the date in the string. Alternatively, you can tell PHP to guess the format: `new DateTime('@'.strtotime($date))`. This, however, is error prone.